# Joining two queries with id

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

So I have two tables: match and player

[image]

winner_id and loser_id is from match table are connected with player_id in player table

and I want to achieve this

[image]

Comment: You should inline the images

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic form of a JOIN:

```
select w.first_name as winner_first_name, 
       w.last_name as winner_last_name, 
       l.first_name as loser_first_name,
       l.last_name as loser_last_name
from match m 
  join player w on m.winner_id = w.player_id
  join player l on m.loser_id = l.player_id
```